# CSS Joomla 3 How do I change the color of an icon

Tags: css, joomla3.0

Sorry about the vague title and I hope it's okay to ask questions about free Joomla3 templates here.

I am working with this template [Joomlage0056 - DesignCanvas](http://demos.joomlage.com/joomlage_0056/) - and I would like to change the color of the Facebook link in the menu bar so that it appears blue, preferably a white font on a blue background, but if that's not possible then a black font on a blue background.

I have (despite my limited CSS knowledge) managed to figure out that this Facebook link is `.nav_facebook a`.  And I have added this to my template (in a special field made for custom CSS)

```
ul#navigation .nav_facebook a  {
    background-color:#3B5998;
}
```

This however makes a blue square behind the white circle, so it's not working as it should.

Any idea how I can achieve this task?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is something that you cannot change in this template. What you are looking at is not a css style but a background image being positioned to the right icon. You can see the image here:

http://demos.joomlage.com/joomlage_0056/templates/joomlage0056-designcanvas/images/sm_icons.png

What you can do is edit this file in photoshop and change the color to what you want it over the icon you want and replace the original file.